# $n_1|2^{n_k}-1,n_ k|2^{n_{k-1}}-1,n_3|2^{n_2}-1,n_2|2^{n_1}-1.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

if $n_1 ,...,n_k$ ($ k\ge 2$) and $ n_i \in \Bbb N$ such that

$n_1|2^{n_k}-1,n_ k|2^{n_{k-1}}-1,n_3|2^{n_2}-1,n_2|2^{n_1}-1.$

then how to prove $ n_1=n_2=...=n_k=1$

I try to solve this from $\equiv$ for example :

$2^{n_k} \equiv 1 \pmod {n_1}$, $2^{n_{k-1}} \equiv 1 \pmod {n_k}$, $2^{n_2} \equiv 1 \pmod {n_3}$, $2^{n_1} \equiv 1 \pmod {n_2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can apply the ideas from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325617/if-p-mid-2n-1-then-how-to-prove-ln-lt-p/325658#325658).

**Hint:** If $n \mid 2^m - 1$, then $l(m) < l(n)$ where $n,m \geq 2$.

The cyclicity of the assumption leads to a non-sense.